# How do I create a map zone?

Tags: google-maps

I have a webpage for my delivery business and I want to show a zone on the map where I deliver. I also want to use that same zone when people sign up for my service. If they are registered for my service and need me to deliver they enter there address into the system. If we don't serve that address the system will tell the, we don't serve it. My code is having a problem entering that zone so please see my two questions.

1. How do I enter my zone on the map so it only shows that section we deliver to in uptown Charlotte.   I can provide the 4 corners of the zone if you need it.
2. How do I enter that exact area within google maps without having to enter ever address on those streets to identify where we deliver?  This will be in the background of my site behind the search button.

Comment: That are to separate questions. Please be more specific, and put some code.

Answer (score 0):

You may find exactly what you're looking for on the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/intro#Paths) looking at Paths in particular.